# After child form is hidden parent is not activated

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 form: A, B, C

Form1 A;

Form2 B, C;

A is parent of B and C

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 formB = null;
    Form2 formC = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        formB = new Form2();
        formB.Owner = this;
        formC = new Form2();
        formC.Owner = this;
    }

    private void showBC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formB.Visible = true;
        formC.Visible = true;
    }
} 
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

1. When application start, form A is show.
2. I open another program (ex: cmd), to active cmd window
3. I click on form A, to active form A
4. I click on button ShowBC -> showBC_Click
5. Form B and C is shown
6. I click button hide on C then B is actived
7. I click button hide on B and I hope A is active (you think so?)
8. cmd window is active

// ==============================================

@Sinatr
I have same problem with only A and B form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 formB = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        formB = new Form2();
        formB.Owner = this;
    }

    private void showB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formB.Visible = true;
    }
} 
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void MsgBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

1. When application start, form A is show.
2. I open another program (ex: cmd), to active cmd window
3. I click on form A, to active form A
4. I click on button ShowB -> showB_Click
5. Form B is shown
6. I click button MsgBox on form B
7. MessageBox "Test" is shown
8. I click button OK on MessageBox
9. Messagebox is closed
10. I click button hide on B and I hope A is active (you think so?)
11. cmd window is active

**I expect A is active in the final step**

**Solution:
Because some child window is not form, like SelectColor Dialog, .. so I need to use win32 api to list child window to active them.
In every child form I need to do that:**

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr parentHandle);

    private static uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr parentHandle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

    public static void SetAppFocus()
    {
        IntPtr topWindowHandle = GetTopWindow(IntPtr.Zero);
        while (topWindowHandle != null)
        {
            if (IsWindowVisible(topWindowHandle) != 0)
            {
                int currentProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
                int processId = 0;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(topWindowHandle, out processId);
                if (processId == currentProcessId)
                {
                    SetFocus(topWindowHandle);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // goto next window
            topWindowHandle = GetWindow(topWindowHandle, GW_HWNDNEXT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know there's a "z-layer" ordering? Meaning that if you close/hide currently top-most window it will focus ( activate ) the window right below? **MAGIC**

Comment: I know, but i think the window right below is A, not cmd

Comment: What happens if you don't mess with `Owner` and `Visible` and just use `Show()` and `Close()`?

Comment: @m.rogalski It's [not quite that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120806-00/?p=6933/).

Comment: This is bug from a application I'm maintaining. My customer need to know why, so I need to explain to him. Above example is a simple application to show the bug, but I don't know if it is a microsoft bug or not.

Comment: @GSerg That's the thing I've missed.

Comment: @CôngQuyềnKnight 1. Its not a "Microsoft Bug" 2. Can't you just `.Focus()` form A when B and C get closed...? 3. It looks like the order of the programs is order of opened not activated.

Comment: @EpicKip Could you please explain more detail? I suggested my customer the solution same as you told, but there are many same bug with original application (many child form) so he deny that solution. Now I need to explain about how this bug happen :(

Comment: @CôngQuyềnKnight your windows have z-index, this is not a bug. And do you suggest coding solutions to a customer?...

Comment: @EpicKip Why not a bug? I think the next active window should be form A not cmd window, shouldn't?

Comment: @CôngQuyềnKnight Its not a bug, its the z index of open windows. The z-index is just incorrect for what you want

Comment: Thanks, finally I need to fix on every child window

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue.

It should be something related to activating `Owner` when **more than one forms has same owner**, because it works correctly with just one `Form2`.

Bug here is that another `Form2` is activated if either one is closed.

Try to

```
void showBC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    B.Visible = C.Visible = true;
    Activate();
}
```

Now everything work "properly": closing either `Form2` will activate the owner.

---

If you want to keep original behavior, then here is a workaround:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    formB = new Form2 { Owner = this };
    formC = new Form2 { Owner = this };
    formB.VisibleChanged += Child_VisibleChanged;
    formC.VisibleChanged += Child_VisibleChanged;
}

void Child_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().OfType<Form2>().Any(o => o.Visible))
        Activate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what exactly problem is? I need an explain to my customer, I try to find any msdn document about this but not found :(

Comment: Also, I have same problem with only A, B. not need C. I will add to first post

Comment: Do not explain anything, fix the problem. Which behavior do you want? See edit.

Comment: Thanks, finally I need to fix on every child window. I tried your solution, but in some case it not work. I will explain in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving it up the OS to figure out which window should be activated when the one with the focus disappears.  What it does here certainly doesn't win any prizes.  Also a pretty big problem with WPF dialogs btw.  *Exactly* why it does this is hard to guess, it just doesn't seem to pay enough attention to the window owner.  Do note that it works just fine when you minimize the window instead of hiding it, why that acts differently is, well, weird.  Let's not hesitate calling it a bug.

The workaround is pretty straight-forward, just don't force it to find another window by itself:

```
    if (this.Owner != null) this.Owner.Activate();
    this.Hide();
```

Also the solution in a WPF app.

Comment: Thanks, finally I need to fix on every child window. I tried your solution, but in some case it not work. I will explain in my answer